# JPA - Many to Many primary key used in another table

Tags: java, jpa, relational-database, entity, persistence

I want to be able to have the list of books in my person entity with the current page for each book.  (A given book collection can be used by multiple people)

I have the following tables:

```
BookCollection
---------------
collection_id
collection_name


Book
---------------
book_id
book_name


CollectionBooks
---------------
cb_id
collection_id
book_id


Person
---------------
person_id
person_name


PersonBooks
---------------
pb_id
person_id
cb_id
current_page
```

The first 4 tables are set up and the relationships are working.  I am confused how I can use JPA for the PersonBooks table.  I believe that is all I need in the database to determine the books a person has and what page they are on in that given book.

Here are the entity classes

```
@Entity
public class BookCollection {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long collectionId;

    private String collectionName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="CollectionBooks", 
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="collection_id", referencedColumnName="collectionId"), 
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName="bookId"))
    private Set<Book> books;
}

@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long bookId;

    private String bookName;
}

@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long personId;

    private String personName;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are your entities? Why do you have a cb_id in CollectionBooks? Why do you have a cb_id in PersonBooks, and not a book_id? You want a person to have books, so the join table should jave a person id, and a book id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I added a cb_id to both tables because in my real data the book in the collection can have unique properties associated with it.  So I needed the collection and the book relationship and that is what I need to attach a value to based on a person.

Comment: None of the tables is a pure join table. So you can't use ManyToMany. A Person has many PersonBooks. That's a OneToMany association. A BookCollection has many CollectionBooks. That's another OneToMany. A PersonBook refers to a CollectionBook. That's a ManyToOne. A CollectionBook refers to a Book. That's a ManyToOne.

Comment: That's what I am thinking.  I think at best I can have a set of PersonBooks objects that will include the amount as well as the Book entity and Collection entity from the CollectionBooks entity.